# Is it possible to call a Interface function from thread?

Tags: java, android, interface

Probably my Question is not that good, but I really don't know how to ask proper.

What I want to do:

```java
public interface cooleInterface {
    void soCoolFunction(String a);
    }
```

My first question is, how do I define the Method?
I want to define the Method in an Activity like:

```java
public void soCoolFunction(String a){
Log.d(TAG, "You Logged " + a);
}
```

and now I want to call it from a Thread like

```java
public class WhatEver extends Thread implements cooleInterface{

public void run(){
@override
soCoolFunction("Hello");
```

Is this even possible? Or how can I call methods from other classes, which doesn't have a Instance from each other, without using statics?

Comment: you can pass the instance of cooleInterface in the WhatEver class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. But, consider that the listener might be null when the thread completes, throwing an NPE...
UPDATE:Code
The thread,

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    MyInterface interface;

    public MyRunnable(MyInterface interface) {
        this.interface = interface;
    }

    public void run() {
        interface.onRunnableDone("Hello")
    }
}
```

the interface,

```
public interface MyInterface{
    void onRunnableDone (String runnableString);
}
```

finally on the activity,

```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

    Runnable r = new MyRunnable(this);
    new Thread(r).start();

    @Override
    onRunnableDone(String runnableString){
        //do something with the string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class WhatEver extends Thread {

   private final CooleInterface listener;

   public WhatEver(CooleInterface listener) {
      super();
      this.listener = listener;
   }

   public void run() {
      super.run();
      this.listener.coolFunction("Hello");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you write this in Java?

Comment: give me 1 minute ^^

Comment: What do I need to pass as listener? what is "YourListener"? A custom listener?!

Comment: it's your interface

Comment: This is working but useless, in android there a 100 ways to get the same result. I could also pass the context, so why should I create an extra Interface?
I look for a way, to execute the Method of class A in class B **without** static or passing a context or reference in any way.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. Sorry. Good luck with that.

Comment: quote @HydroHeiperGen `This is working but useless`. If there are 100 ways to get the same result its better you delete your question or provide a result if you have one.

Comment: The "ways" I was talking about, meant that there are 100 different ways to pass a reference or an instance between two activities or threads but all of them are based on the idea that the first one is directly calling or instantiating the second one.
But I look after a solution where you have two separated things like A and B, and they do not have any intersections. How is it now possible to pass Information between them or how can A execute something in B or the other way round.
I thought maybe an Interface can build that bridge, but it seems like this is the same as passing a reference.

Comment: Is it really embarrassing in your case that A is aware of B's existence?

Comment: @ZachBvy sorry I don't get what you want to say